# In the season 2 finale, does this character live or die?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boys

In the season finale of *The Boys* season 2, does Stormfront die after getting hit with Ryan's eyebeams?

Comment: She seems to be able to speak, despite having severed limbs and an eye deeply punctured by a knife... The questions I'd rather have is how did she get eye-injured by a "regular human", and laser-cut by the child... while she could withstand Homelander's lasers!

Comment: Laser-cut by Ryan makes sense as it is inferred from every superhero who has an heir that the heir contains raw, explosive power(even more than the parent). Even Butcher tells that Ryan is the contingency plan for Homelander. But yes, the knife part doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## She Lives

[As told by Eric Kripke, the showrunner](https://tvline.com/2020/10/09/the-boys-recap-season-2-finale-episode-8-stormfront-alive-dead/)

> No, she’s not dead! She’s Stumpfront! She’s a stumpy little Nazi. **She’s actually not dead**. What we thought was interesting is, if you remember, she ages very, very slowly. **So the best poetic ending for that character is someone who so believed in some kind of pure race finds herself mutilated and having to live with it for potentially centuries felt like a fate worse than death for her**. So no, Stumpfront is not dead. Hashtag Stumpfront lives!

Comment: Homelander also says, in a press conference, that she has been apprehended. It could be a lie (i.e. PR BS) or it could be true.